# How to check if cin is int in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm  writing a program that only accepts int for user input at this point, if its not, keep asking user until get the right integer. Here is the code below:

```
cout << "enter two integers: " << endl;
string input1, input2;
cin >> input1;
cin >> input2;

while (//if they are not integers)
...//ask again
```

As you can see, I use string to store the input, but I don't know how to check this string contains only an integer number.

Comment: That's not a literal duplicate of course, but the answers for your question, and the code to consider are shown there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`cin` will toggle it's `failbit` if the user does not enter a correct data type that it was expecting. Changing the datatype of the inputs to `int` and checking this `failbit` will allow you to validate user input.

```
#include <limits> // This is important!

cout << "enter two integers: " << endl;
int input1, input2;
std::cin >> input1;
std::cin >> input2;

while (!std::cin.good())
{
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    ...//ask again
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use `string` at all.

```
int input1, input2;
cin >> input1;
```

Then you can check if `cin` failed

```
if (!cin) {
     // input was not an integer ask again
}
```

Comment: but that's only valid for non-0 ....
including text.