# How to catch invalid user inputs

Tags: c++

I am not understanding Try, throw, catch statements and am wondering how would be the best why to catch a char when all in puts in your code should be int. It is to help stop people form being silly and putting an "a" when I ask for their favorite number. Here is an example of my code i am trying to protect from someone entering a char when i want ints:

```
int a, b;
std::cout << "Enter a Numerator: ";
std::cin >> a;
std::cout << "Enter a Denominator: ";
std::cin >> b;
```

Comment: To protect from what, exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to throw a C++ exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480640/how-to-throw-a-c-exception)

Comment: I'll saw this forever. Users type characters and strings, not integers. Read the input as a string and do your own validation.

Comment: or better look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/how-to-test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type-and-skip-it).

Comment: When talking about `cin`, the best way to handle errors is `if (!(std::cin >> a))` then check if and *unrecoverable* error occurred, e.g. `eofbit` or `badbit` is set with `if (std::cin.eof() || std::cin.bad())` or whether a *recoverable* error occurred, e.g. `failbit` is set, checking with `else if (std::cin.fail())` after which `std::cin.clear();` can be called to clear `failbit`.

Comment: Don't use exceptions for normal flow control.

Answer (score 2):

If you merge the two answers from the two questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480640/how-to-throw-a-c-exception) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003967/how-to-check-if-cin-is-int-in-c)), I referred to in the comments section of your question, you would get this,

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    std::cout << "Enter a Numerator: ";
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "Enter a Denominator: ";
    std::cin >> b;

    if (!std::cin.good())
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument( "received strings. Need integers" );
    }
}
```

As the first linked answer mentions, you can refer [here](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/2-3.html) for more on what exceptions to throw.

And as the second linked answer mentions, *"cin will toggle it's failbit if the user does not enter a correct data type that it was expecting. Changing the datatype of the inputs to ints and checking this failbit will allow you to validate user input."* .

Just as an after thought, you better check that denominator for zero also, with something like this added to the above code example.

```
if (b /*assuming b is denominator*/ == 0) {
        throw std::overflow_error("Divide by zero exception");
}
```

Comment: Thank you this was a HUGE help. I think i am starting to under stand the try, throw, and catch commands. I just needed to see it from a different angle. Thank you a ton.

Comment: Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

For finer-grained control of your input routines, you need to learn to use the [std::ios_base::iostate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) stream states `goodbit, eofbit, badbit, and failbit`. You can either check the states directly with [std::basic_ios::rdstate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdstate) or use the convenient member functions `.good(), .eof(), .bad() and .fail()`, see [std::basic_istream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream).

While checking `.good()` will tell you you have good input, it doesn't help you recover from failed input or an error condition or `EOF`. For that you have to individually check the error condition that occurred.

Continuing from my comment and adding a bit of detail, you could do something like the following (where you are just doing the same thing for both `a` and `b` -- which could you could move to a function or member function), e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main (void) {

    int a, b;

    /* get input for a */
    while (1)       /* loop continually reading input */
    {
        std::cout << "\nenter an integer for a: ";
        if (! (std::cin >> a) ) {   /* check stream state */
            /* if eof() or bad() break read loop */
            if (std::cin.eof() || std::cin.bad()) {
                std::cerr << "(user canceled or unreconverable error)\n";
                goto unrecoverable;
            }
            else if (std::cin.fail()) {     /* if failbit */
                std::cerr << "error: invalid input.\n";
                std::cin.clear();           /* clear failbit */
                /* extract any characters that remain unread */
                std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),
                                '\n');
            }
        }
        else {  /* on succesful read, just output int and break loop */
            std::cout << "integer a: " << a << '\n';
            /* extract any characters that remain unread */
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),
                            '\n');
            break;
        }
    }

    /* same thing for b */
    while (1)       /* loop continually reading input */
    {
        std::cout << "\nenter an integer for b: ";
        if (! (std::cin >> b) ) {   /* check stream state */
            /* if eof() or bad() break read loop */
            if (std::cin.eof() || std::cin.bad()) {
                std::cerr << "(user canceled or unreconverable error)\n";
                break;
            }
            else if (std::cin.fail()) {     /* if failbit */
                std::cerr << "error: invalid input.\n";
                std::cin.clear();           /* clear failbit */
                /* extract any characters that remain unread */
                std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),
                                '\n');
            }
        }
        else {  /* on succesful read, just output int and break loop */
            std::cout << "integer b: " << b << '\n';
            /* extract any characters that remain unread */
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),
                            '\n');
            break;
        }
    }

    unrecoverable:;
}
```

Note the use of `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` used with `std::cin.ignore` to clear any offending characters that are left in `stdin`. (which essentially extracts up to the maximum streamsize of characters until an `'\n'` is found) Necessary so you next input attempt does not attempt to re-read the same bad characters and fail again for the same reason -- generally resulting in an infinite loop if input is taken within a loop.

Also note the use of the good old `goto` to allow for a graceful exit from the program regardless whether the user cancels input for `a` or `b`.

It's an input routine, so after you write it -- go try and break it. If it breaks, fix it. That about the only way you can catch most corner-cases, e.g.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/cin_validate_ab

enter an integer for a: no
error: invalid input.

enter an integer for a: OK
error: invalid input.

enter an integer for a: 5, I entered 5!
integer a: 5

enter an integer for b: again!
error: invalid input.

enter an integer for b: 6
integer b: 6
```

User canceling input with <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> on Linux (or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windows).

```
$ ./bin/cin_validate_ab

enter an integer for a: (user canceled or unreconverable error)
```

Look thing over and let me know if you have questions.